# Exchange 2003 block group from sending email outside of domain

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2003

150 user organization using AD 2003 / Exchange 2003 - I need to block a group of employees from sending email to anyone outside of the organization.

I've found articles on how to block individuals from doing this through AD, but I'd like to put these users (20+) into a group and block the entire group.

Is it possible to block an entire group? I've read articles on creating a new SMTP Connector but I have to add each user manually it appears. It won't let me add a group (I had created a distribution group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here:  http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/network-administrator/how-to-block-users-from-sending-email-outside-your-exchange-organisation/

[image]